# Why the linear numerator for fractions with irreducible denominators and constant numerators for reducible denominators?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

For example:

$\Large{\frac{2x^3+5x+1}{(x^2+4)(x^2+x+2)}}$ breaks down to $\Large{\frac{ax+b}{x^2+4}+\frac{cx+d}{x^2+x+2}}$

I have been told that since the denominators are irreducible, the numerators will be either linear or constant.

Now my question is for something like $\Large{\frac{2x^3+5x+1}{x^2-4}}$ you would make it equal $\Large{\frac{A}{x+2}+\frac{B}{x-2}}$, why do we assume that the numerators are constant? Why couldn't they be linear??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you divide the denominator into the numerator, getting a remainder.  So, for your example, $$\frac{2x^3+5x+1}{x^2-4}=2x+\frac{13x+1}{x^2-4}$$ and expand the last fraction in partial fractions.  As the denominator now has a higher degree than the numerator, the limit as $x \to \infty$ is $0$, so you don't want a constant term.  In fact, $$\frac{13x+1}{x^2-4}=\frac {25/4}{x+2}+\frac{27/4}{x-2}$$ and you don't want or need a linear term in the numerator.

Comment: I know we don't want a linear numerator but why?? I'm not getting why we let the numerator be linear for an irreducible denominator and make the numerator a constant when the denominator is reducible. Why is this?

Comment: It is the degree counting argument.  In the original the "degree of the fraction" is -1, so the terms need to be as well.  If you have a linear term in the numerator over a linear denominator, the degree is zero.  This is reflected in the limit at infinity.

Comment: @KingSquirrel: also, it is not "a linear numerator for an irreducible denominator" but rather "for irreducible denominator of degree $n$ the numerator has at most degree $n-1$."  Note that this works nicely all the way down to linear denominators, as a linear denominator may be treated as irreducible.

Answer (score 0):

Because remainder of division is always smaller then the degree of the polynomial so we assume it's exactly 1 smaller,and find if the other terms are zero
$$\frac{2x^3+5x+1}{(x+2)(x-2)}=\frac{ax+b}{x+2}+\frac{cx+d}{x-2}=\frac{ax+b-a(x+2)}{x+2}+a+\frac{cx+d-c(x-2)}{x-2}+c=\frac{ax+b-ax-2a}{x+2}+\frac{cx+d-cx+2c}{x-2}+a+c=\frac{b-2a}{x+2}+\frac{2c+d}{x-2}+a+c$$

Answer (score -1):

That is actually incorrect... you need to do polynomial long division first.